# Is TRAY a container?

Tags: semantics

I am working closely with semantic class of *containers*. It's not that obvious though how to define the class. Should it be enclosed? Obviously not, spoon is an example. Could flat surface serve as the container? Tray seems to prove the point. But should we call a table container then? Seems unlikely.

Could you help me figuring the borders of the containers.

Comment: How could anyone decide? Is a bucket, a glass, or a bathtub one? A glass contains liquids. Are you really that a spoon is a container? Suggestion: conduct a psych survey and ask people to classify spoons, sinks, horses, holes and so on as "containers".

Comment: Containers and cups etc are a classic example used by [prototype theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory). You're not going to be able to find good borders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75744/15299

Comment: Not sure if your research is based on English or Russian data. If you can read in Russian, I strongly recommend **Рахилина 2010** *Лингвистика конструкций* - you will need chapter 3, "А был ли концепт? Контейнер и содержимое в русском языке". She reviews relevant literature and specifically answers your question. The whole book is available on Academia.

Comment: @AlexB It's based on Russian data, but given that we work with tangibles it's not a big difference. I've peeked into WordNet and it classifies tray as a container. RuWordNet doesn't.

Comment: @AlexB Thanks for the book reference. It's of much value to me.